# The getValue() method is overridden in two ways. Which one is correct?

Tags: java, constructor

My problem with the following example is that I have read that if you override a function, the return type cannot be changed unless you are overriding in a descendant object, in which case you may change the return type from `ParentClass` to `ChildClass` but that is not the case in either of these cases. We change the return type from String to Object in the first example, and from Object to String in the second one, neither of which are class A or B. Maybe it is the case that you can return a more specific type in any overridden functions?

I: This one is definitely false because you are returning a more general type when overriding.

```
 public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a.getValue());
  }
}

class B {
  public String getValue() {
    return "Any object";
  }
}

class A extends B {
  public Object getValue() {
    return "A string";
  }
}
```

II: This must be the correct one but I don't understand because I thought you could only override from returning type B in class B to type A in class A. That that was the only exception and in previous versions of Java, even that wasn't allowed so I don't see how we can change Object to String.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a.getValue());
  }
}

class B {
  public Object getValue() {
    return "Any object";
  }
}

class A extends B {
  public String getValue() {
    return "A string";
  }
}
```

Comment: This feature is called covariant return. Returning the class type is not necessary or sensible, but that the return type of overriding method can be casted to the return type of overridden method in super class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second is fine, because of this rule in [JLS 8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> *This rule allows for covariant return types - refining the return type of a method when overriding it.*

`Object` is the superclass of `String`, so it's fine for a method previously declared to return `Object` is refined in a subclass override to return `String`.

It's fine because any code which only knows about the superclass method is going to use the return value as `Object`, and it's fine to use any `String` reference as an `Object` reference, e.g.

```
String x = ...; // Anything here
Object y = x; // No problem
```

It sounds like you're getting confused between the two pairs of types here::

- the class declaring the method and the class overriding it
- the return type in the original method and the return type in the override

Those are four completely separate classes - here `B`, `A`, `Object` and `String` respectively.

Comment: Ah, I thought covariant return types were for an object type that the class you're writing from is, and only to be modified when you create a descendant class, from which you obviously can't return a parent class object and all other cases produced errors. It seems that I am allowed to make the return type more specific in any descendant class and that my assumption was wrong. Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

All is about [Covariant return type](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java)

Take a look at this article it will help you.